# translate a .bat to a .sh

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to execute an API on my linux but the problem is : I only have a exec.BAT which is working on Windows.
I have to translate it into en script.sh but i don't know  the equivalent in .sh for a few words in my .bat 
Maybe someone can help me here !
here is my code :

```
set BASEDIR=%~dp0..
```

```
REM Paramétrage de la ligne de commande pour lancer l'application
set APP_NAME=SpectrumViewer
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set JAVA_MAIN_CLASS=com.tcs.ewr.sra.SpectrumViewerFrame
set JRE=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
set JAVACMD=%JRE%\bin\java.exe
set JAVA_OPTS
set REPO=%BASEDIR%\lib
set CLASSPATH="%BASEDIR%"\etc;"%REPO%"\*
REM Version du JRE
"%JAVACMD%" -version
REM Lancement de l'application
"%JAVACMD%" %JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Xms256M -Xmx512M -classpath %CLASSPATH% -Dapp.name="%APP_NAME%" -Dapp.repo="%REPO%" -Dapp.home="%BASEDIR%" -Dbasedir="%BASEDIR%" %JAVA_MAIN_CLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
echo %CLASSPATH%
set ERROR_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

Comment: Why don't you try asking for the specific "few words" you don't know? Otherwise it ends up sounding like you're asking somebody to convert the whole thing.

Comment: yes sorry , i don't know how to proceed with those words :set BASEDIR=%~dp0.. ;

Answer (score 0):

for setting environment variables, use the `export` command for example: `export APP_NAME="SpectrumViewer"`

for print statements you can still use `echo` and you use variables, you need to add a `$` before the variable, for example: `echo "$CLASSPATH"`

shell scripting is SUPER easy to learn and way more flexible than windows batch file scripts; there is a lot more documentation in shell scripting.  Here's a site that you can

---

- setting vars: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec03.html
- using vars: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec05.html
- echo command: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec06.html